# Angular 2 adding styling (css, js)

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs

I have a web style left from angular 1 which includes sass and and bundle of js libs (jquery, bootstrap, animo, etc...) is it possible to integrate them to angular 2? if so, then how? I tried including them into index.html, no errors and no style. I understand that components are view encapsulated. Do you just add them to systemjs and css in index.html?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can, check a sample code below that does exactly that. Of interest to you will be these lines of code:

```
styles: [
   require('./app.component.scss')
],
encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None,
```

The first one imports sass file while the other line allows angular2 to apply the styles globally to the entire angular2 app.

```
import { 
  Component, 
  ViewEncapsulation,
  OnInit 
} from '@angular/core';

import { 
  ROUTER_DIRECTIVES, 
} from '@angular/router';

@Component({
  moduleId: module.id,
  selector: 'ch',
  templateUrl: 'app.component.html',
  styles: [
   require('./app.component.scss')
  ],
  encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None,
  directives: [
    ROUTER_DIRECTIVES,
  ],
  providers: [
  ]
  })

  export class AppComponent{

  }
```

For JS libs the best strategy would be to include them using `npm install {yourlibs} --save` then add them to systemjs build config file. Check this url for more information on how to go about it https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/3rd-party-libs#adding-underscore-library-to-your-project

Comment: But in the end, I will have to rewrite the whole design (html) to separate components with the use of the loaded js libraries right?

Comment: yes you will have to, but it is worthy it. Check this out to accelerate the process http://ngmigrate.telerik.com/topics/

Comment: thanks for clearifying :) First I'll try to redowloading the libraries with jspm and then load them with systemjs.

Answer (score 0):

for external libs just include them on page and use `declare let somelib;` syntax after import statements

```
import {something} from 'sometbing';

declare let somelib;

@Component({...})
export class tralala{

  somemethod(){
    somelib.somethibg();
  }

}
```

and in index.html for example

```
<script src="somelib.js"></script>
```